# VS Code PowerShell Intellisense of AzureAd Module

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

Similar to [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60311260/how-to-add-azure-powershell-module-to-visual-code-intellisense), but for AzureAd, not the Az (and children) modules: how can I get Intellisense working in VS Code for the AzureAd module?  Or other non-default modules? Would it need to be either included in the PowerShell extension or added as a new extension? In other products I've used in the past, I could add local modules to the product's code completion; does VS Code have something similar?

Or is my VS Code install just broken, and this should be working already?